# Tastypie, Django, MySQL permission denied error

Tags: mysql, django, tastypie

I have setup a simple web service, when using just the `python3 manage.py runserver` it works fine, but when I deploy the application to Apache by using mod_wsgi it give the following error:

```
(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 13] Permission denied)")
```

I have also tried using the server's name and then the server's ip and it just replaces localhost in the error message.

Here is a copy of the XML when navigating to the page: http://pastebin.com/QtRzi0X6

#### Edit:

Also I would like to add that I am running on Fedora 20, Python3, Django 1.6, and MariaDB, Also I am use PyMySQL for django and python 3 so it can connect to MySQL

Comment: Check your `DATABASES` setting if it points to the correct database. Check if mysql is running. Check if the user with the password configured in `DATABASES` setting has access to the database. Use mysql console to test whether you can connect to the database host using configured credentials.

Comment: As I mentioned above everything works fine with doing a runserver, the only thing I don't have filled in is PORT but even when I fill it in it is the same error

Answer (score 7):

As it turns out (After hours of searching and testing), this is actually a apache/mod_wsgi problem, just type the following command to allow apache to make database connections:

```
    setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

Comment: This is usually only for Red Hat based OS's including Fedora and Centos.
This was such a vague error for what it was related to. it turns out that in this particular case SELinux was the issue. before you issue this command, I would suggest that you issue a `setenforce 0` and then try again. if it then works you know that SELinux is causing a block and that you should apply the above command.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This has been bothering me for a whole week. I fond no solution until I tried this!

Comment: 6 years on and still saving time, what a priceless share - thanks so much!